# How to use Flutter Route Navigation for dynamically changing elements (partials) in screen

Tags: flutter

I have an application that dynamically replaces widgets on the screen depending on user interactions, meaning that the user can toggle different partial views (widgets) on the same screen when he presses a button - for example to display a form once the user pressed a button.

For navigation *between screens*, I use the `Navigator` with `MaterialPageRoute`'s. These work well, but only for pushing or popping full screens.

How can I use the Navigator and probably a custom implementation of `Route<T>` to be able to dynamically switch widgets on a particular screen if the user is on that screen?

The desired outcome is that I can navigate to a PageRoute `/alternative` using the Navigator and depending of the current screen, the following happens:

- If the current screen is the screen that can show the desired widget in a placeholder (that currently displays another screen) -> switch to that partial widget within that screen
- If the current screen is another screen -> switch to the screen that can show the partial widget and display the partial widget within that screen

Currently I am storing the index of the displayed partial screen in a variable in the state of the screen but I want to use the Navigator so that I can navigate there from everywhere.

Is that possible?

Comment: can you please show some gif or pics that explain what you want to achieve to get the whole picture

Comment: @karimtarek unfortunately I don't have a gif but please find an image [here](https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-qYIXRi4Lgn4/WxesGzit6_I/AAAAAAAAB1c/t-6piTCUeUUT63jxp4_hvrNJU_CvSHDTACLcBGAs/s1600/1_yZgMX0qV2fScc_CJ8tXgEQ.png). Imagine the Screen Layout Widget currently displays a Text Widget. If the user now presses a button, I want this Text Widget to become an TextField Widget. I have that already but I want to know how to do this with the Navigator and Routes.

Comment: so you want to make something like editting the user name or a comment ? is that right? if so you don't need to make this with navigator and routes , because navigator is used when you want to go from screen to another . I can do it in another way but not with navigator